# Is there a way to lock the volume & brightness on iPad/iOS 10 from getting changed by a child?

Tags: ios, ipad

My little boy watches stuff on our iPad all the time, the smart monkey figured out how to change the volume and the brightness by pulling up the Control Center and adjusting them via the slider.

My problem is that he sets them to the maximum no matter how many times I tell him not to do that. Is there a way to lock them on a certain level? or disable the Control Center?

Edit: Sadly redeagle's solution never worked, I have no idea what is "Volume Limit" in the restrictions used for but my kid can still control the volume using the control centre and/or the side switch

[image: Volume Limit]

[image: Control Centre]

[image: Volume]

Answer (score 3):

For brightness, you can go in Settings > Control Center and change if you want access to Control Center on the lock screen or within apps, it will always be available on the home screen, AFAIK.

To prevent him from changing the volume, change the volume to what you always want it to be and go to Settings > General > Restrictions and tap Enable Restrictions, then set a Restrictions passcode (something different than the normal passcode). Go to Volume Limit and check Don't Allow Changes.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings- > Control Center.
Turn off Access on lock screen.
Turn Off Access within apps.
This way you can avoid your kid accessing brightness adjustment from lock screen and within apps.

After turning off the above the 2 settings, the Control Center will be accessible only from home screen.

This way you can control to some extent. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to set sound limit on all apps, but you could use Guided Access for only one app (like YouTube) with locked sound level: [Use Guided Access with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612)

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of how to lock the display brightness level setting worked for me.

Go to general/ display accommodation/ reduce white point.

Push white point to max.

Problem solved for brightness

Comment: Which version of iOS where are talking about here?

Answer (score -1):

Go to general/ display accommodation/ reduce white point.

Push white point to max.

Problem solved for brightness

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your answer doesn't answer the question that was asked, at least not how it's currently worded.  In addition, it's wrong in that the path to the menu selection is missing a step.  You can [edit] the answer to fix it so it actually answers the OP's question.  See [answer] for tips on providing a good answer.  - From Review